# Get file path and file name from directory - C#

Tags: c#, filenames, filepath

I am trying to get the file path and file name of I file I upload in a folder. I have the paths like so:

```
string path = Path.Combine(_webHost.ContentRootPath, "Uploads\\ZipFiles\\");
string extractPath = Path.Combine(_webHost.ContentRootPath, "Uploads\\ExtractedFiles\\");
```

I upload my file in `path` and I unzip the file in `extractPath`.

```
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(extractPath);
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(extractPath);
```

`fullPath` returns the correct path but `fileName` is empty. I don't get the file name.
I am trying to get something like this

`var dbfPath = "C://ExtractedFiles//fileName.jpg";`
I was planning on getting the file path in one variable and the file name in another and then concatenate them but I can't get the file name. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Since this line: string fileName = Path.GetFileName(extractPath); get extractPath as input, and that contains no filename, it cannot return a filename :-)

Comment: `extractPath` in your example is a path of a directory and not a file. If you want to get filenames inside that directory you can use `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(extractPath)`

Comment: extractPath doesn't contain any filename but it contains a end directory name (extractedfiles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the files in the ExtractedFiles folder :

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(extractPath)
```

If your zip have folders inside, and you want to get all the file inside them recursively use :

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(extractPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```